# m4a audio bit rate increases after concatenate using AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to concatenate two m4a audio files from ios device library and I got success in that, here is the code I am using -

```
 AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];
 AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                      initWithAsset: songAsset
                                      presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
NSLog (@"created exporter. supportedFileTypes: %@", exporter.supportedFileTypes);
exporter.outputFileType = @"com.apple.m4a-audio";
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{}.....
```

When I examined these files, bit rate for original files was 16 kbps only but after AVAssetExportSession files were at 192 kbps…so it seems that the AVAssetExportSession increases the bit rate for the resultant file. Does anyone have the solution for the problem like these or is there any way to specify bit rate for the resultant file???

Comment: Try to export using the **bold** AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough preset like this :- AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                      initWithAsset: songAsset
                                      presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

If you're sure the format of your AAC/m4a files is the same you *could* do what you want by extracting the raw AAC (aka adts) stream from the files, concatenating the raw packets, then wrapping the results back in an m4a container. This should get rid of the bitrate blowout you're seeing *and still be playable*.

The following file played back fine for me.

```
cat file1.aac file2.aac > catted.aac
```

Try it yourself:

```
afconvert -d aac file1.m4a file1.aac
afconvert -d aac file2.m4a file2.aac
cat file1.aac file2.aac > concatenated.aac
afconvert -f m4af concatenated.aac concatenated.m4a
```

To translate this shell script into `AudioToolbox` code you would do something like this

```
AudioFileReadPackets(/*from file1.m4a*/);  // all of the packets
AudioFileWritePackets( /* to concatenated.m4a */);
AudioFileReadPackets(/*from file2.m4a*/);  // all of the packets
AudioFileWritePackets( /* to concatenated.m4a */);
```

This should be fast as there is no decoding/encoding (only packet parsing) and the resulting file's bitrate will not change significantly.

**Older**

I think it’s odd that `AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A` is changing your bit rate - my experiments left the bit rate unchanged. However I was using using a *single* AAC/m4a file.

If you’re using `AVAssetExportSession` to concatenate multiple files and export them as AAC/m4a, I don’t think you can avoid bit rate changes (what happens when the bit rates in the multiple files differ?), however choosing the resulting bit rate is another story.

As you’ve noticed `AVAssetExportSession`’s control over export parameters is limited to a handful of presets. For more control, I would use an `AVAssetWriter`. When you create your `AVAssetWriterInput` you have a [dizzying array of options](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009937), including `AVEncoderBitRateKey`.

If you wanted to stay with `AVAssetExportSession` and only wanted a lower bit rate version of your audio you *could* export as `AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie` with either the `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality` or `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality`. Of course then you’d have a .mov file instead of m4a, but another run through `AVAssetExportSession` as `AVFileTypeAppleM4A/AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A` would fix that. These two presets lower your bit rate by converting to mono 22 & 44.1 kHz audio, respectively. It doesn’t sound great.

Comment: What I am doing is recording two files with AVAudioRecorder in m4a format having same settings (i.e. bitrate) and trying to concatenate them but the resultant file is having much more bit rate than the two.

Comment: Ah, in that case you can concatenate the raw AAC packets and then wrap the result in an m4a file. In this case you shouldn't see the bitrate increase.

Comment: That seems like a good question. But how to use those AudioToolbox methods? They seems complicated. They have a lot of parameters to fill in. Will have to look out how to use them.

Comment: That's what stack overflow is for!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mp4box` in the command line.

Command:

```
mp4box -cat 1st.m4a -cat 2nd.m4a -new D:\Joined.m4a
```

I haven't tried this with two `m4a` files having different bitrates, but with same bitrate it works.